# kibana - programatically return saved search objects and associated data via REST API

Tags: node.js, rest, elasticsearch, kibana

I am currently working on an excel export tool for kibana using node.js. Right now I am trying to figure out if it is possible to export the data associated with a saved search within my selected kibana index.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

1. User provides authorization and selects a project within kibana that they have access to.
2. Once a user has selected a project, any saved searches associated with that project are populated into the UI.
3. The user selects a saved search, report name, and date range, and submits the form. The application then makes a request to the kibana index and returns the data associated with the selected search and within the given time range.

I have finished the authorization and UI, but I am currently stuck trying to figure out how to return the saved search objects within a specific project. I am also unsure of how to construct the request to the kibana index that would return the data associated with the selected saved search within the given time frame.

Does anyone have any experience with something similar to this? I am also very new to Elasticsearch, is this sort of functionality possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by a wonderful Elastic team member here:

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/exporting-saved-search-data/90843